# process executed by exec keep on running

Tags: node.js, electron

By using NodeJs I am executing a process, everythin is working fine only problem is the process exe keep on running even if parent app is killed/closed.

For example a code to kill a process

```
require('child_process').exec(require('./globalconfig').CMD_BASE_PATH + 'taskkill.exe /im finder.exe /F', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    require('./loggerHelper').logger.error(error)
  }
})
```

By this "finder.exe" gets killed but If I observer Task Manger then "taskkill.exe" keep on running. What I suppose is after killing finder.exe taskkill.exe should get terminate, Why this is happening and how I can solve this?

Comment: I can't think of reason that `taskkill` could return a result to node before exiting. Does `taskkill` stay running every time it is `exec`ed? Does using `.spawn` result in different behaviour?

Comment: @Matt Yes, `taskkill` keep on running every time and hey!! I just tried with `.spawn` and worked as expected killed the process and `taskkill` gets terminated. Any reason why `.spawn` working and why not `exec`?

Comment: `.exec` launches a shell to run the process, `.spawn` runs the process directly as a child of node. So prefer `.spawn` unless you need the shell to do something before running the command (like expand variables).

Comment: That's not a reason why though, just the difference. As mentioned, I wouldn't expect `exec` to have run the callback before the process has exited. Maybe the shell exits somehow before taskkill? Does stdout/stderr include anything interesting?

Comment: @Matt nothing so much intresting other than if process is not found then `process.exe is not found` error and message. I guess you pointed it correctly as after `exec` I am executing `app.quit()` for electron to quit but as `exec` is async application gets quit but the process taskkill.exe may or may not be started yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) spawns a shell to launch the required command, either `process.env.ComSpec` or `cmd.exe` on Windows.  This adds an additional layer between `node` and the process being launched. Although that's not a complete answer as to why the process might remain running, using `exec` does provide more area for issues to occur.

Using [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) allows the parent `node` process to directly control and pass signals to the child process.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const { CMD_BASE_PATH } = require('./globalconfig')
const find = spawn(`${CMD_BASE_PATH}taskkill.exe`, ['/im', 'finder.exe', '/F'])

find.stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log('stdout: %s', data)
})

find.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.log('stderr: %s', data)
})

find.on('close', code => {
  if ( code !== 0 ) console.error(`Finder exited with error: ${code}`)
})
```